# How can I disable Blend version control without disabling it in Visual Studio?

Tags: wpf, xaml, version-control, blend

I have a solution with lots of projects inside it, when I build it on **Blend** - the version control with the status message `Get status` appears ~5 times which takes a lot of time and loading (~10 seconds). The version control I'm using is TFS. When I want to commit the changes I'm using the VS anyways. I don't really need the Blend to follow the source control rules.

Is there any way to disable the versioning for Blend and keep it on for Visual Studio?

The solution itself has lots of COM objects, but I'm trying to change the .xaml part of WPF.

**EDIT**

Just add Blend to firewall settings as blocked